# The Grassmannian of 2-planes in complex n-space is hyperkahler

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have seen it mentioned that the Grassmann manifold of complex 2-planes in complex n-space is a hyperkahler manifold, but I can't find a reference for a proof. Does anyone know the proof of this or have a reference for it? In particular I'd like to see a proof that uses hyperkahler reduction.

Comment: Hum... what do you mean by a hyperkahler manifold? It can't be "compact Kahler manifold with a Kahler metric with $\mathrm{Sp}$ holonomy", because then the metric would be Ricci-flat and the first Chern class of the manifold zero, and Grassmannians have nonzero first Chern class.

Comment: I think that I'm wrong and the Grassmanians are quaternion-Kahler, but not hyperkahler. Sorry, I'm confused about the relationships between quaternion-Kahler, hyperKahler, and hypercomplex structures. Anyway, I'd still like to see a reference which discusses the quaternion-Kahler structure of the Grassmannians.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just isomorphic to $SU(n)/S(U(n-2) \times U(2)).$ So you just need to find isotropy subrepresentation acting like $Sp(1)$